# How to change nginx's default homepage via a Dockerfile and then launch it by running a container

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

I have a very simple HTML file which outputs '`Container with HTML file`'.

I have this Dockerfile where I copy my `welcome.html` (my simple HTML page):

```
FROM nginx:latest
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY welcome.html welcome.html
```

Then I create an image in the directory containing this HTML page:

```
docker image build -t html_nginx .
```

and run a container using:

```
docker container run -p 80:80 --rm html_nginx
```

But when the container is run on port 80, I get the default '`Welcome Page`' of nginx and not my desired output from the HTML file ('`Container with HTML file`').

How much ever I try, I have never been able to get my message printed on the browser.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

The default nginx config will load the `index.html` file from the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory.

This default is set in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` with the lines

```
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

So to fix this you can copy `welcome.html` into the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory as `index.html`, or change the above `index` line to reference `welcome.html` and reload. To make this change more permanent you would likely want to create a dockerfile that defines a docker image overriding the config copied in where you have already set this value.

Alternatively you should just be able to access `/welcome.html` when hitting your server e.g. `http://localhost:80/welcome.html`

Comment: Changing my HTML file's name  to index.html worked! I was able to get my desired homepage

Comment: I really new to Docker and I really dont know where to specify the 'location' block to make the change more permanent

Comment: I use Docker Quick Start Terminal on Windows 10 and specifying the location block in my Config file leads to error when the config file is run :(

Comment: You can't really change config that easily. It will fallback to the default one upon container start https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/aqy1i0/docker_overwriting_nginx_defaultconf_every_restart/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access your container:

```
docker exec -i -t <container_name> /bin/bash
```

Now you need to find you index.html file

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and now, you can change your index.html file with this command

```
sed -i -e 's/OLD_TEXT/NEW_TEXT/g' index.html
```

e.g:

```
sed -i -e 's/nginx!/FELIPE-System/g' index.html
```

Finish!